# Determine all functions for a given gradient

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't really have an approach to solve this problem so it would be very kind if you could tell me what to do first:

> Determine all functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ for which applies:
>
> $\forall(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: \nabla_{(x,y)}f = (x,y)$

I know that the gradient $\nabla$ is a vector containing the partial derivatives of $f$:

$\nabla f = \left(\begin{array}{c} f_{x_1} \\ f_{x_2} \\ ... \\ f_{x_n} \end{array}\right)$

But how does this help me determining the sought functions?

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for a function whose derivative with respect to $x$ is $x$ and whose derivative with respect to $y$ is $y$. Here is one such function:
\begin{align*}
f(x,y) &= \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{y^2}{2}
\end{align*}
See if you can generalize this result.

Comment: I'll try it: When $\frac{df}{dx} = x$ and $\frac{df}{dy} = y$, the corresponding antiderivatives are $\frac{x^2}{2} + A$ and $\frac{y^2}{2} + B$, so $f(x,y) = \frac{x^n}{n} + \frac{y^n}{n} + C$ would be a solution.

Comment: I think you mean $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}+C$, which is correct.

Comment: Yes, of course. :-) And that's all I have to do? That's the most general function? Well, that's almost too easy …

Comment: Just to highlight the exceptional case : Given the gradient, it is not necessarily true that you can always find a function from which it can be derived i.e the potential function. Given a multi-variable function, finding the gradient is easy but one can't do vice-versa all the time. check this page for details http://mathinsight.org/conservative_vector_field_find_potential cheers, abiyo